# Boas Práticas ao modularizar uma aplicação com EF e multi-banco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, modelagem, entity-framework-6

Digamos que eu queira modelar uma aplicação em `.NET` utilizando o `EntityFramework` como ***ORM*** e utilizar uma de suas vantagens, ser "genérico" para vários ***RDBMS***.

Então, por exemplo, eu quero que minha aplicação aceite trabalhar com `Firebird`, `SQL Server` ou `MySQL`. Que na instalação da aplicação o usuário possa selecionar qual `SGBD` ele quer e então as configurações serem feitas.

**Porém, digamos também que eu vá ter comandos *SQL* customizados para cada banco de dados em determinadas tarefas.**

Logo, crio meu módulos com projetos ***Class Library*** assim:

- **Application** - Contendo as regras de negócio, feito para ser consumido pelas camadas que requisitam determinadas tarefas à aplicação;
- **Domain** - Que contém as classes que representam as tabelas do banco de dados;
- **DAL** - Ondem tem as classes que contém os métodos de requisição ao EF para os métodos da aplicação;
- **Repository** - Que conterá minha classe herdada de `DbContext` e suas propriedades `DbSet<>`;

Essa seria minha abordagem inicial.

**Como eu faria para então poder ter minha camada DAL específica para cada *RDBMS*?**

**Ou melhor, quais são as boas práticas a serem adotadas diante desse cenário?**

**Como lidar com as referências/dependências das *DLL´s*?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atualmente utilizo o EF em aplicações minhas em Windows Forms e na Web.
Para utilizar multiplos bancos de dados, a única diferenciação é a string de conexão.

Porém já alerto que para fazer funcionar alguns SGDBs terá uma pequena dor de cabeça, mas depois de tudo ok e instalado funciona perfeitamente.

As minhas aplicações sigo o padrão:

Database:
Nesta pasta tenho o ERPDBContext.cs, que possui o DbContext e os DbSet. Exemplo:

```
public class ERPContext : DbContext
{
    public ERPContext()
        : base("ConexaoERP")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ERPContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UsuarioAcesso> UsuarioAcesso { get; set; }     

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().ToTable("Usuario");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UsuarioAcesso>().ToTable("UsuarioAcesso");
    }
}
```

Se notar utilizo o Database.SetInitializer(null); para não criar a base de dados.

As minhas classes eu faço na pasta Model, um .cs para cada "tabela"/classe. Neste model, como eu uso o EF, faço uma classe herdada para facilitar a vida no desenvolvimento. Exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using FlexGestor.Helpers;
using System.Data.Entity;
using FlexGestor.Interface;

namespace FlexGestor.Models
{
    public class BlogCategoria : IEntidadeBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int BlogCategoriaID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Seção")]
        public int BlogSecaoID { get; set; }
        public string Sigla { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        /* Campos fixos */
        public int EmpresaID { get; set; }
        public string Fixo { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Apagado { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DtApagado { get; set; }
        public int UsuCad { get; set; }
        public DateTime DtCad { get; set; }
        public int UsuAlt { get; set; }
        public DateTime DtAlt { get; set; }
        public int UsuUltAlt { get; set; }
        public DateTime DtUltAlt { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UsuCad")]
        public virtual Usuario UsuarioCad { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UsuAlt")]
        public virtual Usuario UsuarioAlt { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UsuUltAlt")]
        public virtual Usuario UsuarioUltAlt { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("EmpresaID")]
        public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BlogSecaoID")]
        public virtual BlogSecao BlogSecao { get; set; }
    }

    public static class BlogCategoriaExt
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Listagem> Listagem(this DbSet<BlogCategoria> entities, int secaoID)
        {
            return entities
                .Where(u => u.Apagado == "N" && u.BlogSecaoID == secaoID)
                .OrderBy(r => r.Descricao)
                .Select(l => new Listagem { Key = l.BlogCategoriaID, Texto = l.Descricao });
        }

        public static IEnumerable<BlogCategoria> ToListERP(this DbSet<BlogCategoria> entities)
        {
            var usuarioLogado = HttpContext.Current.Session["usuarioLogado"] as UsuarioLogado;
            return ToListERP(entities, usuarioLogado);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<BlogCategoria> ToListERP(this DbSet<BlogCategoria> entities, UsuarioLogado usuarioLogado)
        {
            return ToListERP(entities, usuarioLogado.EmpresaIDLogada.GetValueOrDefault(0));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<BlogCategoria> ToListERP(this DbSet<BlogCategoria> entities, int empresaID)
        {
            return entities.Where(w => w.EmpresaID == empresaID && w.Apagado == "N");
        }

        public static ResultadoListagemPadrao Grid(string orderna, string ordenaTipo, string filtro, int? filtroID, UsuarioLogado usuarioLogado)
        {
            ERPContext db = new ERPContext();
            var resultado = new ResultadoListagemPadrao();
            var dados = db.BlogCategoria.ToListERP(usuarioLogado);
            var where = "";            
            var id = 0;

            if (int.TryParse(filtro, out id))
                where = " CategoriaID == " + id.ToString();

            resultado.TotalRegistros = dados.Count();
            if (filtro != null)
                where = " Descricao.Contains(@0) ";
            resultado.Dados =
                (from a in dados.AsQueryable()
                 select new
                 {
                     CategoriaID = a.BlogCategoriaID,
                     a.Sigla,
                     a.Descricao
                 })
                .Where(where, filtro)
                .OrderBy(orderna + " " + ordenaTipo);
            return resultado;
        }
    }
}
```

Para os models, eu utilizo interface, assim posso fazer um evento para popular os dados do usuário.

Eu estou implementando assim.

Update 1:

Conforme comentário de dúvidas, editei a resposta.
Então vamos lá. Quando comecei a mexer com EF e C#, não tinha muito conhecimento. 
Porém em todos os sistema que desenvolvo coloco os campos que estão na **IEntidadeBase**. 
Tem gente que vai me perguntar porque estrutura, simples, com ela vou no registro e vejo as informações do mesmo rapidamente.

```
public interface IEntidadeBase
{
    int EmpresaID { get; set; }
    string Fixo { get; set; }
    string Status { get; set; }
    string Apagado { get; set; }
    DateTime? DtApagado { get; set; }
    int UsuCad { get; set; }
    DateTime DtCad { get; set; }
    int UsuAlt { get; set; }
    DateTime DtAlt { get; set; }
    int UsuUltAlt { get; set; }
    DateTime DtUltAlt { get; set; }
    Usuario UsuarioCad { get; set; }
    Usuario UsuarioAlt { get; set; }
    Usuario UsuarioUltAlt { get; set; }
    Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
}
```

Depois é só utilizar a interface nas classes. Mas o que isto vai me ajudar, simples, com ela você pode fazer um metodo de quando for salvar, você chama o método e ele insere os valores de cadastro. Mas porque fiz assim? Na versão do EF4 não tinha como fazer um DbSet generico, não sei se nas novas tem.

Agora vamos falar do BlogCateriaExt e o this. Com esta classe eu consigo fazer assim:

```
db.BlogCateria.ToListERP();
```

No meu caso, isto é interessante, pois segue todas regras do sistema. Ai tenho outros eventos ou melhor, outros retornos. O retorno Listagem, serve para isto mesmo, para retorna as informações de uma forma que fique mais fácil usar em combobox.

Além disto, meus models extendidos tem o método Grid, que é um retorno padrão para montar listagem.

E para finalizar, porque tudo isto em um .cs só? Simples, para não ter que ficar andando muito para um lado para outro.

Espero ter sanado as dúvidas, qualquer coisa dá um grito.

Comment: Editei a resposta principal. Qualquer coisa dá um grito.

Comment: Seu exemplo é muito bom, mas creio que isso não responde a seguinte problemática apresentada: **`Porém, digamos também que eu vá ter comandos SQL customizados para cada banco de dados em determinadas tarefas`**. Apenas mudar a string de conexão não resolveria.

Comment: @TiagoPSilva funciona assim. O próprio ORM cuida disto para você. Se você fizer db.BlogCategoria().Count(), o ORM sabe o que tem fazer para cada banco de dados. Essa é vantagem de usar um ORM. Mas claro usando Linq para fazer as pesquisas. Se fazer na mão os SQL, casos especificos ai deve tratar na mão.