# Quais são as camadas de uma aplicação web?

Tags: aplicação-web, mvc, arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software

Em uma aplicação simples para desktop em `C#`  `Windows Forms` por exemplo e modelo em camadas pode definido da seguinte forma :

**Camada de Apresentação**

Windows Forms, GUI (Janelas para interface com usuario).

**Camada de Regra de Negócio**

Classes escritas para definir a regra de negocio.

**Camada de Acesso a Dados.**

Classes escritas para realizar operações com a base de dados (CRUD).

- **E no desenvolvimento web como funciona essa divisão das camadas ?**

**Obs :** Exemplos serão bem vindos.

Comment: Não domino o assunto, mas parece que acabou que você mesmo já se respondeu.

Comment: Não cara tipo no desenvolvimento web temos arquivos e uma estrutura diferente no projeto,  e isso que quero saber , to achando que não consegui me expressar muito bem rs.

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas no modelo Web temos as mesmas camadas, a diferença é a camada de apresentação, que será de forma web (html, por exemplo). Tanto que você pode (não digo que deve ou que não, e sim que pode) usar a camada de negócio e a camada de Acesso a Dados que usa em seu sistema WinForms.

Comment: Eu diria que essa pergunta é ampla demais, até porque não é definido o modelo arquitetural que as respostas precisam se basear, então a divisão de camadas pode ser em cima de qualquer coisa. Seria legal limitar mais a pergunta.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez estou trabalhando nisso pretendo reformular a pegunta , estou dando uma lida nos conceitos antes , mas sei lá acho que não consegui me expressar direito não ><.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você mesmo disse que modela GUI dessa forma. É a sua forma, não de todo mundo, não a mais adequada para todas as aplicações. Tem quem prefira ter menos camadas, tem quem prefira ter mais e tem quem prefira ter outras camadas ou pelo menos não considerar tudo como camada. [Onde tratar cada coisa pode variar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94065/101).

Para web pode fazer o mesmo, use o mesmo modelo ou [crie/use um outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/101).

Hoje em dia é bastante comum usar o padrão [MVC para web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4474/101). Algo que [pode ser usado para GUI também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85848/101) e é muito parecido com o descrito. Há uma [comparação sobre isso aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23668/101). Tem até [variações de como o MVC é aplicado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22399/101).

Tem pergunta específica sobre o assunto para [ASP.NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223/101) e para [PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114824/101). Não estou validando que as respostas lá contidas sejam definitivas sobre o assunto, muito menos desqualificando. Também tem uma [definição geral do padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/101).

Há questionamentos de como usar cada parte do MVC como [se o *controller* é necessário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60830/101). Sempre há [controvérsias do que vai onde](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/67911/101). [O que pode usar em cada "camada"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86834/101).

Há diferenças se a página será [renderizada no cliente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73714/101) ou no servidor.

Há controvérsias sobre uso do DAL ou [DAO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113840/101), [BLL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23324/101), sobre uso do padrão [Repository](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12927/101), ou [como ele deva ser usado com outras técnicas específicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51536/101), entre outras coisas. Ou [como modularizar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15277/101) em geral.

Há quem opte por MVC porque todo mundo está fazendo. Nem sempre é necessário trabalhar dessa forma. Em PHP os pragmáticos continuam fazendo sem um **modelo** e um **controlador** claramente definidos. Muitas vezes nem separa exatamente a **visão**. O problema só ocorre quando a pessoa usa um padrão onde tudo está junto sem saber porque ou por preguiça. Se a pessoa puder justificar adequadamente, não precisa de camadas na maioria das aplicações, pelo menos não desta forma.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

É basicamente o mesmo. O que descreveu acima é o MVC. Model Control View.

A camada de apresentação seria a **V**iew.

A regra de negócio é o **M**odel (Business  Model, Business logic).

A camada de acesso a dados é o DAO (Data access object) e faz parte do Model.

O **C**ontrol do MVC é o mecanismo que liga as camadas Model e View.

Para exemplos e mais detalhes, veja esse tópico: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116422/4793

Answer (score 0):

Estava escrevendo o texto abaixo como um comentario, mas acabou ficando um pouco extenso.

Uma coisa que não gosto no termo `3 camadas`, é que eu nunca sei se você está se referindo a `3-layer` ou `3-tier`, a nossa ligua acaba criando uma confusão entre estas duas arquiteturas.

Em todo caso, espero que não confunda `MVC` com `3-layer`, apesar de ser possivel fazer uma relação entre `Model -> Presentation`, `Controller -> Business` e `Model -> Data Access`.

O padrão `MVC` é um `Design Pattern` utilizado para fazer uma separação logica da interface do usuario, enquanto que o `3-layer` é uma Arquitetura.

por exemplo, podemos ter uma aplicação feita em `MVC` com apenas 2 camadas, onde construimos a nossa `Apresentação` e `Regras de Negocio` dentro do `MVC`, neste cenario `Apresentação` e `Regras de Negocio` acabam se comportando como uma camada unica, porém a camada de Acesso à Dados ainda está isolada (`Banco de Dados`).

por outro lado, podemos remover as `Regras de Negocio` da `Controller` e implementar as mesmas em outro lugar, por exemplo em um `WebService`, neste caso passamos a ter três camadas.

Se preferir você pode mover a sua `Apresentação` para o cliente, por exemplo usando `SPA` por exemplo, e manter a sua `Regras de Negocio` em uma `API RESTful`

E por fim ainda podemos criar mais camadas, por exemplo outras camadas de `Apresentação`... `Desktop`, `Aplicação Mobile`, `Web`, etc... dividir as `Regras de Negocios`, por exemplo `Financeiro`, `Contabil`, `Operacional`, etc... e até mesmo o camada de `Acesso a Dados`... `NoSQL` (e.g: `MongoDB`) e SQL (e.g: `SqlServer`).

Em todo caso, nem sempre MVC é o melhor para o projeto. em alguns projetos `2-layers` é mais que o suficiente, em outros pode ser necessario usar `n-layers`, o mesmo vale para o `tiers (2, 3 ou n)`, afinal o sistema ser escalavel nem sempre é o mais importante.