# Estrutura/Organização Projeto C#

Tags: c#, padrão-dao

Tenho um projeto que estou desenvolvendo em camadas, até agora tenho as seguintes: Acesso a dados, apresentação, negócios e objetos de transferência. A dúvida é a seguinte:

Exemplo: Tenho um `form` para cadastrar uma pessoa jurídica no banco de dados. Para salvar os dados que o usuário inseriu no `form` seria correto neste `form` que o usuário inseriu os dados eu criar um objeto `pessoaJuridica` e passar este objeto para uma classe na camada de negócios com o nome de `SalvaPessoaJuridica.cs` por exemplo, esta por sua vez acessa a camada de acesso a dados e efetua a gravação no banco?

Para cada `form` eu teria que criar uma classe para manter os dados ou eu já usaria a camada de acesso a dados diretamente no form e já manteria os dados sem criar uma classe específica para cada tipo de operação?

Exemplo:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtNome.Text == string.Empty || txtIdade.Text == string.Empty || txtEmail.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Informe os valores para nome, idade e email do aluno.");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                string sqlInsert = "Insert into Alunos (Nome,Idade,Email) values (@Nome,@Idade,@Email)";
                string[] campos = { "@Nome", "@Idade", "@Email" };
                string[] valores = { txtNome.Text, txtIdade.Text, txtEmail.Text };
                accDB.Salvar(campos, valores, sqlInsert);
                gdvDados.DataSource = accDB.getRegistro(sqlSelect);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
     }
```

Ou:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             try
            {
                Alunos aluno = new Alunos();
                aluno.Nome = "Teste";
                aluno.Idade = 22;
                aluno.Email = "asd@asd.com" 

                SalvaAluno salva = new SalvaAluno();
                salva.Manter(aluno);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: A segunda opção facilita a manutenção do sistema. Qualquer novo integrante de sua equipe conseguirá entender facilmente o que é feito neste código. Observação: Cuidado ao exibir mensagens de exceção para o usuário final e muito cuidado principalmente ao concatenar strings para montar uma query. Você pode abrir uma brecha de segurança em seu sistema.

Comment: [Realcionado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122309/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-camadas-de-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-web?noredirect=1&lq=1). Esta pergunta e **as perguntas vinculadas** podem dar uma visao melhor do que fazer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu segundo exemplo é o que chegou mais próximo das melhores práticas, pois ele está aplicando o conceito de [separação de responsabilidades](http://www.devmedia.com.br/amadurecendo-com-separation-of-concerns/18699).

Esse segundo código é algo bem parecido com que os conceitos [MVC](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2367/abordando-a-arquitetura-mvc-e-design-patterns-observer-composite-strategy.aspx) ou [MVVM](http://www.macoratti.net/11/06/pp_mvvm1.htm) fariam por exemplo.

No primeiro exemplo a camada de apresentação está sendo responsável por lógica de inserção no banco dados, como criar a instrução SQL e salvar. A responsabilidade do form é coletar e exibir dados.

Essa sua classe `SalvaAluno` seria uma espécie de repositório se estivesse usando o [Repository Pattern](http://www.macoratti.net/11/10/net_pr1.htm), pois ela apenas adiciona entidades do tipo aluno.

Para seu código atual ficar melhor ainda em vez de utilizar a classe `SalvaAluno` diretamente, você poderia utilizar uma interface `ISalvaAluno`para aplicar conceitos de [injeção de dependência e inversão de controle.](http://www.devmedia.com.br/inversao-de-controle-x-injecao-de-dependencia/18763) Dessa forma você não se preocuparia com o tipo de implementação da sua camada DAL, essa implementação poderia ser tanto com Entity Framework, Dapper etc

Para tudo isso citado há muito conteúdo disponível nesse site e na web.

Respondendo sua pergunta:

> Para cada form eu teria que criar uma classe para manter os dados ou
>   eu já usaria a camada de acesso a dados diretamente no form e já
>   manteria os dados sem criar uma classe específica para cada tipo de
>   operação?

Você teria que criar uma classe para persistir dados para cada form(ou melhor para cada entidade) para que haja separação de responsabilidades.